# Extracting only a particular set of data from a URL with an Excel File

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am looking to gather all the data from the penultimate worksheet in [this](http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/uknom05_mdaily.xls) Excel file along with all the data in the last Worksheet from "Maturity Years" of 5.5 onward. My code is below. I am currently just combining all the data from both sheets. I don't know how to extract only data associated with "Maturity Years" of 5.5 onward in the Last Worksheet.

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlrd 

url = 'http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/uknom05_mdaily.xls'
socket = urllib2.urlopen(url)

xd = pd.ExcelFile(socket)
df1 = xd.parse(xd.sheet_names[-1], header=None)
df2 = xd.parse(xd.sheet_names[-2], header=None)

bigdata = df1.append(df2,ignore_index = True)
print bigdata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add: `df1 = df1.loc[:, df1.loc[3, :] >= 5.5]`, where `df1.loc[3, :]` assumes the maturity is always on the 4th line of the sheet.

Comment: BTW, I noticed that there are some extra sheet names in `xd.sheet_names`. Not sure where they come from, but you should reconsider using the `-1` and `-2`, and instead match on name.